# mysql unable to connect to data base in vb using 000webhost.com

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a MySQL data base that 000webhost.com is hosting visual studio gives me an error "Host 'IP address **.**.***.***' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server" 
                               /
here is my code for connecting /
                               /

```
        MySQLConnection.ConnectionString = "server=000webhostserver;Port=3306; User ID=username; password=password; database=my database name"
    MySQLConnection.Open()
```

please help!!! :(

Comment: It seems to be a problem on the permissions on the webhostserver database

Comment: yeah you need to upgrade your account but i dont want to

Comment: I mean you need to connect to your account and set the permissions on your mysql db to allow connections from outside. Usually you need to set the IP address of the computer allowed to connect or set to Any Host. Sorry but I don't have an account on their service, so I cannot be more precise.